# Calulate the sum of total present in a row - Dynamic HTML Table

Tags: mysql, dynamic, sum, html-table

I have a dynamic HTML table. Which has A,B,C,D,E... Columns. My data as well as columns are dynamic. I haved added a new column total at the end. Where i need to add the values present in each column and put it in the last

```
-----  -----  -----  -----  -----       -------
  A      B      C      D      E   ....   Total
-----  -----  -----  -----  -----       -------
  -      -      12     1      -           13
  4      -      -      -      -           4
  -      3      2      5      -           10
```

I have been referring to this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/unKDk/21/). But could not change the code into my requirements. How do i calculate total for `dynamic` columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget to add the same WHERE clause criteria from your first query to your Summary query

```
SELECT A, B, C, D, E FROM [table]
UNION
SELECT SUM(A) AS A, SUM(B) AS B, SUM(C) AS C, SUM(D) AS D, SUM(E) AS E
FROM [table]
```

Comment: Thanks. But i am using some pivot tables. i am re-arranging my columns and rows. This wont work for me. Thanks for your time